# Reverse Proxy Bad Gateway after adding OIDC to my SPA

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nestjs, keycloak, openid-connect

im in the process of adding keycloak to my company existing SPA written in Angular.

I have managed already to get the acess_token from keycloak as the initial auth works well, but when im trying to talk to my API, roughly half the requests throw a 502 bad gateway error.

When I test locally everything works well and flawlessly, I am now testing it on our development kubernetes cluster.

The scheme is like this :

- Web app (angular SPA served by an nginx server), the nginx server acts as a reverse proxy to talk to my api
- Api server (written in nestJS, with a server side validation of my access token)

The NGINX server talk to the Api server using a clusterIP kubernetes service.

I belive the problems comes from the token validation on the api that for some reason doesnt work sometimes or takes too long and thus throw an error.

This is what it looks like :

```
@Injectable()
export class ownKeycloakStrategy extends PassportStrategy(BearerStrategy, 'keycloak') {
  
  constructor(private readonly openidService: OpenidService, private readonly staffService:StaffService,
    private readonly adminService:AdminService) {
    
    super(
      (token, done) => this.validate(token, done)
    );
  }

  async validate(token, done): Promise<any> {
   var userInKC = null
    try {
      userInKC =  await this.openidService.validateToken(token);
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
    // get Info from KC, if you cant means either user doesnt exist or token is not valid
    //console.log(userInKC)
    if(!userInKC) return done(new UnauthorizedException('Token not valid'))
    // complete user object with info from our db
    const userX: any = await Promise.all([
              // here searches for user in own db
              
          ]).then(x => x.find(e => e !== null));
    if (!userX) return done(new NotFoundException('User not found'))
    // here we set up the user of the rerquest so our service can work properly
    const user = {
      ...userInKC,
      _id: userX,
      status: userX.status
    }
    return done(null, user, {scope: 'all'});
  }
}
```

My validateToken function :

```
public async validateToken(token) {
        try {
            const public_key = await this.public_key()
            if(public_key) {
                const decrypt = await this.keycloak.jwt.verifyOffline(token, public_key);
                return decrypt.content
            }
        } catch(e) {
            return this.keycloak.jwt.verify(token);
        }
    }
```

What i tried :

- Changing the proxy buffering of my nginx conf to allow for the bigger access_token header
- Try calling my api directly (i also get a bad gateway error, this time i belive from traefik (my cluster load balancer)

Thank you for any help any of you could provide, p^lease let me know if you need to know something

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This feels like you shoild first ensure that it is not an API error handling issue. Test the failure scenarios first, using the curl tool, and run the API locally:

- Call the API without an authorization header
- Call the API with an invalid token such as 'xxx'

```sh
curl -i http://localhost:3000/somepath \
-H "Authorization: Bearer xxx'
```

You should then get a controlled response such as an error object, along with an HTTP status of 401. The response may need an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in order for the SPA to be able to read the response and take the right actions.

**RELIABLE JWT VALIDATION**

These are two most common JWT failure scenarios for APIs:

- A client sends an invalid or expired token - this WILL happen so the API must handle this case and return a 401
- The API expeeiences a failure downloading token signing public keys - the API must return a 500 in this case, since the SPA cannot resolve this and needs to display an error

**SOMETHING TO COMPARE AGAINST**

If it helps see [this Node.js code example of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts) and note that it aims to return error responses that work well for the client, as well as logging details in the API.

**NGINX**

It is worth understanding what this is doing. The most common setup is to just use the [proxy-path directive](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) which passes entire requests and responses through, including all headers.

**INFRA**

Perhaps there is a deeper infra issue such as a load balancer or NGINX routing to an unhealthy API server. You ought to be able to follow this scientific approach though:

- No API logs so the request is not reaching the API
- No NGINX logs so the request is not reaching the reverse proxy
- Therefore it is a problem that the infra guys must resolve